# How can I get the width and height of a component in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I've designed a loading component for the forms input elements in my angular forms to be displayed while the fields are loaded from the api. Here, I have to provide the height and the width of the component to the `app-loader` component so that it can occupy space accordingly.

For now what I have done is manually use a switch-case and provide heights and widths within that. However, this is hard since I have many other input types to be developed and also it's even harder to make it responsive. My question is, is there a more efficient way to dynamically pass the height and the width of the component relevant to that particular switch case to the `app-loader` component?

What I have so far is shown below.

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="!formInput.loaded"
  [ngSwitch]="formInput.type">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="FORM_INPUT_TYPE.CHECKBOX">
    <app-loader width="409" height="24"></app-loader>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="FORM_INPUT_TYPE.IMAGE_DROP_AREA">
    <app-loader width="414.66" height="96"></app-loader>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="FORM_INPUT_TYPE.RATING">
    <app-loader width="409" height="30"></app-loader>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>
    <app-loader width="645" height="39.75"></app-loader>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the element ref of the component in the constructor like this:

```
...
private elem: ElementRef,
...
```

Then you can get the native element by `this.elem.nativeElement`.
Then you can get the height and width by `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth`.
If you want a particular div, just use `@ViewChild()` and do the same.

Tip: Usually you will retrieve the height and width in the `ngOnInit`.
However, depending on your situation, you may want to do it in `ngAfterViewInit`, or subscribe to the scroll event with the `@HostBinding()` directive.